# Extend fibre bundle

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds, fibre-bundles

Let $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$ be a smooth fibre bundle. Suppose $W$ is a smooth manifold such that $F=\partial W$.

When is it possible to extend the bundle to a bundle over $B$ with fibre $W$?

Comment: Do you mean the extension to be a bundle over $B$, or can it be over some manifold containing $B$?

Comment: @MarkGrant thanks for the comment, I edited my question.

Comment: Perhaps again I am saying things you know. In the universal case, you are asking for the existence of a section of $B\text{Diff}(W) \to B\text{Diff}(F)$. This will not have an answer in full generality, so let me specialize to $W = D^n$ so something can be said. When $n \leq 3$, a section exists (and the space thereof is contractible) by the Smale conjecture. For $n$ large and even, the calculations [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf) by Waldhausen and Farrell-Hsiang give...

Comment: that $\pi_4 B\text{Diff}(D^n, \partial) \to \pi_4 B\text{Diff}(D^n)$ cannot be injective, which contradicts the existence of a section. At a glance $n \geq 16$ should suffice, but I was not careful in comparing to the FH result. (I would be surprised to see a section of the above map for any $D^n, n \geq 4$ or $5$ or so.)

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks a lot, I was not aware of that! I'll have a look at it and refine my question if needed.